Identify grouped rows based on multiple conditions using PowerQuery
I have such a table



Code
Column A
Column B
Column C
Level
Column D
Column E




1234
Cell 1
Cell 1
Cell 1
25
Cell 1
Cell 1


1234
Cell 2
Cell 2
Cell 2
50
Cell 2
Cell 2


1234
Cell 3
Cell 3
Cell 3
50
Cell 3
Cell 3


1234
Cell 4
Cell 4
Cell 4
75
Cell 4
Cell 4


5678
Cell 5
Cell 5
Cell 5
10
Cell 5
Cell 5


5678
Cell 6
Cell 6
Cell 6
disabled
Cell 6
Cell 6


5678
Cell 7
Cell 7
Cell 7
20
Cell 7
Cell 7


5678
Cell 8
Cell 8
Cell 8
100
Cell 8
Cell 8


9090
Cell 9
Cell 9
Cell 9
disabled
Cell 9
Cell 9


9090
Cell 10
Cell 10
Cell 10
disabled
Cell 10
Cell 10


9090
Cell 11
Cell 11
Cell 11
disabled
Cell 11
Cell 11


9090
Cell 12
Cell 12
Cell 12
disabled
Cell 12
Cell 12



I have grouped rows by "Code" and grabbed all values, so I ended up with mini tables. I want to identify those codes where the column "Level" in each mini table contains at least a "disabled" and other values.
Referring to the above table I should get as output only code 5678.
I managed to add a custom column "HasDisabled".
How can I filter out the codes that have all "disabled"?
M-code
let
    Source = #"Import",
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Code", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Code"}, {{"Tables", each _, type table [#"Code"=nullable text, #"Column A"=nullable text, #"Column B"=nullable text, #"Column C"=nullable text, #"Level"=nullable text, #"Column D"=nullable text, #"Column E"=nullable text]}}),

     #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "HasDisabled", each
    let
        Levels = [Tables][#"Level"], ContainsDisabled = List.Contains(Levels, "disabled", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    in
        ContainsDisabled)
in
    #"Added Custom"


Try this:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", Int64.Type}, {"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", type text}, {"Column C", type text}, {"Level", type any}, {"Column D", type text}, {"Column E", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Code"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Code=nullable number, Column A=nullable text, Column B=nullable text, Column C=nullable text, Level=any, Column D=nullable text, Column E=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each 
if List.Contains( [All][Level], "disabled")  and List.Count( List.RemoveItems([All][Level],{"disabled"})) > 0 then true else false)
in
    #"Added Custom"



Awesome! Is there a way to then "ungroup the rows" previously grouped to go back to the original table look, without the rows for the codes I am not interested to so, looking back at the table I will have only the rows for code 5678.

Filter Custom to TRUE and then expand the nested table in the All column (split arrows in the column header)
